# Convert node.js cryptography code into dart

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, cryptography

I need to sign message in dart using Ed25519 algorithm.

I have such implementation in node.js, but have troubles converting it into dart.

Here is my node.js code:

```
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("ed25519");

const userBasePublicKey = publicKey.export({ format: 'der', type: 'spki' }).toString('base64');
const userBasePrivateKey = privateKey.export({ format: 'der', type: 'pkcs8' }).toString('base64');

console.log("base64 private_key:", userBasePrivateKey)
console.log("base64 public_key:", userBasePublicKey)

const message = 'Test message';
const signature = crypto.sign(null, Buffer.from(message), privateKey);
console.log("Signature: ", signature.toString("base64"));
```

On Dart I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography.

source code:

```
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

test('test key pair logic', () async {
    final algorithm = Ed25519();
    final keyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();

    final message = utf8.encode('Test message');

    final signature = await algorithm.sign(message, keyPair: keyPair);

    keyPair
        .extractPublicKey()
        .then((value) => print(base64.encode(value.bytes)));

    keyPair
        .extractPrivateKeyBytes()
        .then((value) => print(base64.encode(value)));

    final signatureBase64 = base64.encode(signature.bytes);
    print(signatureBase64);
}
```

On Dart my public and private keys are 32 bytes long, but on node.js it is 44 and 48 bytes long accordingly.
How can I achieve same behaviour for my Dart code?

```
final publicBase64 = 'MCowBQYDK2VwAyEAhbI14Sb4SJFRUU/IuIaeZKuoEGZ1eJIJCTDBU3XH3Yo=';
final privateBase64 = 'MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEID5dnoErClBkzVC+hLi6UvrE3nq3UashcLur+nEFNrJM';

final publicKey = SimplePublicKey(base64.decode(publicBase64), type: crypto.KeyPairType.ed25519);

final testKeyPair = SimpleKeyPairData(base64.decode(privateBase64), publicKey: publicKey, type: crypto.KeyPairType.ed25519);

final message = utf8.encode('Test message');
final signature = await algorithm.sign(message, keyPair: testKeyPair);

final signatureBase64 = base64.encode(signature.bytes);
print(signatureBase64);
```

Also, if I tried to create public and private key in Dart code from generated keys in node.js, but my signature was not the same as in node.js code.

Comment: In the Dart code the _raw_ keys seem to be used, in the NodeJS code keys in _PKCS#8_ (private key) and _X.509/SPKI_ (public key) format. Check if the Dart library you are using can also generate/import the keys in PKCS#8 or X.509/SPKI format. Otherwise you have to explicitly convert between the different formats.

Comment: Topaco, thanks for your response . Yes, I know this. Library doesn't support this king of import. Question is in that how can I make this import by myself?

Comment: For Ed25519 the PKCS#8 format (private key) is: `0x302e020100300506032b657004220420 + <32 bytes raw private key>` and the SPKI format (public key) is `0x302a300506032b6570032100 + <32 bytes raw public key>`. If you Base64 decode your example keys `MC4C...` and `MCow...` you can verify this.

Comment: @Topaco, yes, this is clear. But I am afraid that I can't tell this for ```await algorithm.sign(message, keyPair: testKeyPair);```. So, is it only way to create own implementation of this algorithm?

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear to me what you actually want. Don't you want to use the private key from the NodeJS code in the Dart code to create the same signature? Then you just have to Base64 decode `MC4C...`, remove the leading part `0x302e020100300506032b657004220420` and Base64 encode the rest again (and analog for the public key).

Comment: @Topaco, understood.
Thanks a lot!!!
Works fine now :) Signatures are same.

Comment: @Topaco That DER boilerplate (0x302...) was extremely helpful. Thank you!